# How to perform Load/Performance testing on jBPM6 (kie-workbench)

Tags: jboss, jmeter, drools, jbpm, kie

I need to perform load testing using jmeter/other tool. I need to test the performance of the application when multiple human task requests executed like starting a process, assigning the tasks, listing the tasks and form submitting for human task etc. Currently jbpm6 (jbpm-console) war file was deployed in tomcat (remote machine). I tried to record jbpm 6 ( kie-workbench) login page in Jmeter using recording controller and HTTP(s) test script recorder. After submitting valid username and password the application just stopping at "Please wait Loding application....". I tried in both Chrome and Firefox. I am not sure whether i am doing it in correct way or not. Kindly let me know which is the best way do load/performance testing on jbpm 6 or share some information regarding how to perform load/performance testing on jbpm6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend conducting load testing via JBPM Console as it isn't something which normally happens. Only limited number of users like admin, analysts, developers, etc. have access.

In order to create the load and do multiple task start, assignment, listing, etc. operations I would rather go for [JBPM Remote API](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html). In that case it should be enough to provide credentials via [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and configure JMeter to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json` via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for detailed configuration instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest also to keep an eye on [Benchflow](https://github.com/benchflow/benchflow) a set of tool to benchmark process engines based on BPMN2.0 standard.

note: I'm not affiliated with this project